# Magento 2 how to use sales_quote_save_after Event?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I would like to call an observer called 'salesQuoteSaveAfter' in magento 2 but it is not working could you please guide me or suggest me  whether i did mistake.

**File Paths:**

1) app/code/Ewall/CustomPrice/Observer/SalesQuoteSaveAfterCustom.php

```
namespace Ewall\CustomPrice\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class SalesQuoteSaveAfterCustom
{   
    protected $checkoutSession;

        public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession)
        {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        }
    public function invoke($observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('invoke function is calling');

        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        /* @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */

        if($quote->getIsCheckoutCart())
        {
        $this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId($quote->getId());
        } 
     }
}
```

2 ) app/code/Ewall/CustomPrice/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_quote_save_after">
<observer name="Ewall_CustomPrice_Custom" instance="Ewall\CustomPrice\Observer\SalesQuoteSaveAfterCustom" />
</event>
```

could you please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
namespace Ewall\CustomPrice\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class SalesQuoteSaveAfterCustom implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('invoke function is calling');

        $quote = $observer->getQuote();

        /* @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */

        if($quote->getIsCheckoutCart())
        {
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId($quote->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rana ji its calling now but i unable to get quote details like id..etc how can i get ? .

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `events.xml` in `etc` directory Instead of `frontend/events.xml` I don't know the exact reason why `sales` events are behaving like this may be some `Magento` expert can give the exact reason. I know this because I had similar problem some time ago

And If you want to use this event only for front-end then you can put `events.xml` in `etc > webapi_rest > events.xml`